# problem in hibernate DAO (session already closed!!)

Tags: hibernate, session

I have implemented DAO as  follows,

//pseudoCode

```
public MyDAO{

  private Session session;
  MYDAO{
  this.setSession(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession());
  }

  public void save(MyObj obj){
   //save obj in db
  }
}
```

Now i have used the dao to save a single object it works fine.Now if save two object inside seperate transcation i get a error saying "session is already closed"

EG

```
Feature feature = new Feature();
feature.setFeatureName("testf333");

FeatureDAO featureDAO = new FeatureDAO();
Transaction tx = featureDAO.getSession().beginTransaction();
featureDAO.makePersistent(feature);
tx.commit();
System.out.println("successfully save in db " + feature.getId());


tx = featureDAO.getSession().beginTransaction();  //getting error here
Feature feature4 = new Feature();
feature4.setFeatureName("4444");
featureDAO.makePersistent(feature4);

tx.commit();
System.out.println("successfully save in db " + feature.getId());
```

I think this problem can be solved by checking if session is closed .But where can i set a new session because i use the session from DAO to start a transcation

Comment: It's early Saturday morning in the US, so many of us may be asleep.  Replies aren't always quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to hold onto the `Session` in your `MyDAO`, you're probably best off holding onto just the `SessionFactory`, and getting a session from is when needed, by defining your `getSession` method in `MyDAO` as

```
public Session getSession() {
   return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

or just save nothing related to session handling in `MyDao` at all and use

```
public Session getSession() {
   return HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
}
```

A hibernate session is tied to a specific thread and closed on commit, but the session factory's `getCurrentSession()` method gets a new session as needed so that you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: I don't see an edit since the title change hours ago.  What's your current issue?